# Moving Configuration Directories and Files to a Sub-directory of Home Directory

Tags: configuration, directory, home-directory

Is it possible to move all configuration directories and files (Dot-directories and dot-files.) inside a sub-directory of my home directory?

I always have hidden files and directories shown, so I hate seeing all those dot-directories and dot-files right inside my home directory.

If it is possible to create a sub-directory called "config" inside my home directory and move all my config files and directories inside that, it'll be ideal!

So, is this possible? Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible move your config to another directory, but i have good alternate for You can keep hidden and not showing it on your home directory by type ctrl+h on your home directory.

Comment: What is that way of moving config to another directory? Because I need to see all files and directories, including dot-files and dot-directories.

Comment: you can get it [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/194342/how-to-back-up-and-migrate-your-linux-configuration-files/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any global way to do this. You can do it on application by application basis (and probably not for all applications).

Comment: Actually I am looking for a way to permanently change the directory in which configuration files and directories are stored; in a way that future configurations will be stored there as well.